# Adding multiple HTML pages in Django efficiently

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

I have created a simple Django application which features a single HTML page for each US state. Each state page extend base.html but features different content.

URLs are stated in the URLs.py file and the rendering of the pages is mapped in views.py.

I'd like to know how I could scalably grow thw number of pages to hundreds or perhaps thousands, all with different names, without having to explicitly state each in the views.py and urls.py files.

What's the correct way to do this?

**HTML files**

```
base.html    
states_info_app/index.html
alabama-weather.html
alaska-population.html
arizona-schools.html
arkansas-hospitals.html
california-restaurants.html
colorado-colleges.html
connecticut-gyms.html
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'states_info_app/index.html')

def alabama(request):
    return render(request, 'alabama-weather.html')

def alaska(request):
    return render(request, 'alaska-population.html')

def arizona(request):
    return render(request, 'arizona-schools.html')

def arkansas(request):
    return render(request, 'arkansas-hospitals.html')

def california(request):
    return render(request, 'california-restaurants.html')

def colorado(request):
    return render(request, 'colorado-colleges.html')

def connecticut(request):
    return render(request, 'connecticut-gyms.html')
```

**URLs.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from states_info_app.views import index
from states_info_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('states', views.states, name='states'),

    path('alabama-weather', views.alabama, name='alabama'),
    path('alaska-population', views.alaska, name='alaska'),
    path('arizona-schools', views.arizona, name='arizona'),
    path('arkansas-hospitals', views.arkansas, name='arkansas'),
    path('california-restaurants', views.california, name='california'),
    path('colorado-colleges', views.colorado, name='colorado'),
    path('connecticut-gyms', views.connecticut, name='connecticut')
]
```